How to apply Sans Serif to all text and math
I spent a lot of effort recently to apply sans-serif font to my text and math as well. I always have at least one of the problems:

Units are not displayed in the same font family as text.
Greek letters are not sans-serif.

I have the following MWE:
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %... accepts Latin accentuation

\usepackage[scaled=1]{helvet} %... sets text font to helvetica
% \usepackage{sansmathfonts}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{isomath}        %... handles mathrm to match text font (?)
\usepackage{upgreek}        %... provides upright greek letters
\usepackage[helvet]{sfmath} %... sans serif helvetica in math mode

\usepackage{siunitx}
%... para unidades de medida
    \providecommand*{\Ohm}{\text{$\upOmega$}}
    \providecommand*{\micro}{\text{$\upmu$}}

\title{Apply sans-serif font to text, math and Greek}
\author{J. B. Lima Filho}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Using sfmath package}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Compare unit \si{AU} with AU text: ok!
    \item Greek letters: $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, ..., $\psi$: not ok!
\end{itemize}


\section*{Using sansmathfonts}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Compare unit \si{AU} with AU text: not ok!
    \item Greek letters: $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, ..., $\psi$: ok!
\end{itemize}

\textit{Obs.:} Error messages:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Font shape `OT1/xcmss/b/n' in size \textless 17.28\textgreater\ not available
    \item Font shape `TS1/xcmss/m/n' undefined
    \item Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
\end{itemize}


\end{document}

See below the results. Obs.: for Using sfmathfonts, I uncomment sfmathfonts and comment out both helvet and sfmath.

Does any one have a clue?

Is this for a presentation or poster? Otherwise, using 100% sans is not recommended, from the point of view of typographical quality and readability.

It is for a paper. I recently submitted a paper on ACS and the editor returnd it requiring  me to select a sans-serif font. I selected helvetica, but I feell the difference between math and text fonts very unpleasent. NOTE: everything looked perfect in the original paper version for which I used Times New Roman.

You need to look at the documentation for the packages to figure out the options which make sense. But you are currently ending up with bitmap CM, which cannot be good. But you have to configure e.g. isomath and siunitx and sansmathfont etc. to do what you want. Just loading conflicting font packages will only make a mess ;).

I see... I am not expert in LaTeX. Could you give-me a clue on how to configure?

Usually journals make decisions about fonts etc. Don't they tell you what to use? As for configuration, have you actually looked at the documentation?

The editor recomended to use either HELVETICA or ARIAL.

OK, so presumably not a LaTeX person. Read isomath's documentation, maybe. It's 12 years old, so maybe there's something better, but it is newer than lots of the other packages you list. Note that isomath and siunitx are focused on correctness according to standards. That means some things should be sans, yes, but it also means others should be serif. Similarly for upright versus italic.

If you decide what you're actually trying to use, it will be easier to help. (Though somebody may come along with a ready-made solution.) Are you submitting PDF or source? If the former, consider a unicode engine. Then you just need to find a maths font and text font you're happy with. Whereas for (pdf)TeX, you're dealing with a patchwork.

Helvet would be nice!

Maybe hvmath package is worth checking out.

@bubaya doesn't work :/

@Brasil Are you open to using an unicode engine like lualatex?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I never tried anything different from LaTeX. So, I have no idea on how to start with luatex...

Can you show in your question what exactly you tried with sansmathfonts? If I do \documentclass{article} \usepackage{helvet} \usepackage{sansmathfonts} \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} \usepackage{siunitx} \begin{document} \begin{itemize}     \item Compare unit \si{AU} with AU text: ok!     \item Greek letters: $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, ..., $\psi$: ok! \end{itemize} \end{document} it seems to work fine https://i.sstatic.net/UR6HHFED.png

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, if you uncomment \usepackage{sansmathfonts}, it overrides \usepackage{helvet} nulling it completely. Thus, either use one or other. Using ´´´helvet´´´ along with sfmath, text and math fonts are fine, except for Greek letters. This combination is great especially when I need \mathrm to write units, like cm, min, kg, etc (unit fonts are the same of the text). To apply sansmathfonts, it is necessary to deactivate helvet and sfmath: the Greek letters now are awesome, but \mathrm doesn't provide the same text font =/

@Brasil sansmathfonts is for sans serif computer modern font. If, as your question title suggests, you just need a sans serif document, but not necessarily a specific font, then it will work fine.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, as I said: it works fine just until I need to use converting to days, a month is $30~\mathrm{days}$ or converting in days, a mont is \SI{30}{days} (here, the unit days displays in a font family different from the word ´´´days´´´ of the text)

@Brasil  https://i.sstatic.net/UmZxmjoE.png

Doesn't work for me: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AhXYsrQvuhQzg4QR0YSQfEqlKyI6zA?e=nq3zPF

https://www.overleaf.com/read/hvjvynfnsysy#6cb734

Worked!!! Thank you so much!!!

I just found out that adding the fouriernc package solves the problem with using helvet:
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} %... sets helvet as text font
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{fouriernc}      %... controls math fonts
\usepackage[helvet]{sfmath} %... sets helvet to math fonts
\usepackage{isomath}        %... handles mathrm to match text font (?)
\usepackage{upgreek}        %... provides upright greek letters

\usepackage{siunitx}

\title{Apply sans-serif font to text, math and Greek}
\author{J. B. Lima Filho}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Using helvet package}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Compare unit \si{AU} with AU text: ok!
    \item Greek letters: $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, ..., $\psi$: not ok!
\end{itemize}


\end{document}



If the aim is just to get a consistent sans serif document, but not necessarily Arial or Helvetica, you could switch to an unicode aware engine like lualatex and use for example lato fonts like this:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage{lete-sans-math}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Compare unit \si{AU} with AU text: ok!
    \item Greek letters: $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, ..., $\psi$: ok!
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


(see Which OpenType Math fonts are available? for more available fonts)

If you prefer to stick with pdflatex and the computer modern sans serif:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Compare unit \si{AU} with AU text: ok!
    \item Greek letters: $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, ..., $\psi$: ok!
\end{itemize}

\end{document}



This looks awesome, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz! I would love to dive in LuaLaTeX, but I don't know how to do it. What is unicode engine? What is the problem with LaTeX? I spent so long time using LaTeX, but still feel like aprentice. I just checked that overleaf has LuaLaTeX, but when I choose it, the compilation of my project fails. I feel lost...

@Brasil The above code works with an up-to-date texlive2024. lete-sans-math was only recently renamed to this name, on old latex distributions, try lato-math instead

+1 Thanks for the Lato font!

@Dr.ManuelKuehner You're welcome! I happened to recently see the announcement about the renaming on ctan, so I thought I could give it a try in this answer :)
